# What do you call a matrix of the form $\left(\begin{smallmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a \end{smallmatrix}\right)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, terminology

I'm reviewing a piece of python code that uses the term "rotations" for these matrices, but of course that's not quite accurate. What's a good, more accurate term of similar accessibility?

Here are my candidates so far:

- **scaling-and-rotation matrix**: Clunky, but the best I've got right now.
- **scaled rotation**: Less clunky than the above. This term might sound like we're scaling the *amount of rotation*.
- **conformal matrix**: Technically correct, but far fewer people will understand the meaning compared to "rotation matrix". Also, it's a bit ingenuous since the term *conformal* prototypically refers to nonlinear maps that behave infinitesimally like these matrices.
- **angle-preserving matrix**: A more accessible form of *conformal matrix*. Less knowledgeable readers may be distracted trying to figure out which $2\times2$ matrices are angle-preserving. (Readers who understand the term *conformal matrix* will probably already know this.)
- **[multiplication by a] complex number**: Not as accessible as "rotation". Also a bit clunky since it identifies a complex number with its representation.
- **sum of a scaling and antisymmetric matrix**: Worst suggestion so far, especially since antisymmetric matrices don't show up anywhere in the code or code comments.

Is there any standard, accessible term for such linear transformations? I'd also appreciate thoughts on whether I'm mistaken about how accessible and/or clunky the terms above are.

Comment: I don’t know what they are called, but the ring composed of these real matrices is isomorphic to the complex numbers. It is the usual representation of complex numbers as matrices.

Comment: Over an arbitrary commutative ring, $R,$ the ring of such matrices is isomorphic to $R[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle.$

Comment: **Comformal mappings** are exactly what you are describing. The term extended and popularised to mean any analytic function that was locally comformal.

Comment: There are other angle-preserving matrices (they are products of the matrices you described and reflections). These are the orientation-preserving and angle-preserving matrices, i.e. conformal matrices.

Comment: I don't think there's a term you can confidently use without explanation.  I'd go with "complex analogs" and a note explaining the meaning.

Comment: The relation to complex numbers is particularly stark when you realize that a function $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$ satisfying the Cauchy Riemann equations is equivalent to the Jacobean of $f$ being of this form.

Comment: I mean, I learnt it that way over 10 years ago when I took linear algebra for the first time, back by an old Jewish mathematician (he was in his late 60s in the early 2010s, when I was about 18). He used such terms as "Orthogonal transformations", "Special transformations", "Comformal transformations", "Involutionary transformations", etc and told us that many of this terms, which are _a priori_ defined for linear functions only have meanings beyond linear functions to mean _locally_ that type of function.

Comment: Sum of a diagonal and an antisymmetric matrix — not just any $2 \times 2$ diagonal matrix, but one where the two diagonal entries are equal (otherwise, one would get matrices of the form $\left(\begin{smallmatrix} a & -b \\ b & c \end{smallmatrix}\right)$ where $a$ is not necessarily equal to $c$).

Comment: @ThomasAndrews that is because linearity in $\mathbf{C}$ implies $T(az) = aT(z)$ where $a$ is any complex number, and we all learnt in 1st year that "any comformal (linear) function can be represented by multiplication by a complex number."

Comment: If you don't mind inventing an acronym for the purpose, you could call it a "RIC" (Ring Isomorphism from ℂ) matrix.  And if you want to emphasize the fact that it rotates (while incidentally scaling) a number in the complex plane, call it a "RIC Roll" 

Comment: The overall construction is a *representation* of $\mathbb{C}$ -- could probably be called the standard two-dimensional real representation of $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: (For the algebraic group of invertible matrices) Deligne torus, First time I hear this name. if $i\in K$ then it is $GL(1)\times GL(1)$, if $i\not \in K$ then it is $Res_{K(i)/K} GL(1)$

Comment: ["roto-reflection"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_rotation) is a not-uncommon term for the composition of a rotation and a reflection. I've seen "roto-scaling" a time or two (including [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2783991/409)), but I don't have an authoritative reference.

Comment: The matrix is usually called a *dilative rotation* in journal papers (if one negates the second column, the resulting matrix is called a *dilative reflection*), but this term is seldom seen in textbooks.

Comment: Another suggestion (not supported by literature AFAIK): what about a "Similarity Matrix"? People who study geometry in school will be familiar with "similar" shapes, and these matrices will map shapes to similar shapes. Unfortunately, it suffers from the same downside I pointed out in my previous comment: reflection will also produce similarity. But, the term is sufficiently evocative, so maybe you might tickle your fancy?

Comment: @TheoBendit it looks like Wikipedia at least thinks [spiral similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiral_similarity) is a good option.

Answer (score 5):

If $a,b \in \mathbb R$ then $\left(\begin{smallmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a \end{smallmatrix}\right)$ can be written as $\left(\begin{smallmatrix} r\cos \phi & -r\sin \phi \\ r\sin \phi & r\cos \phi \end{smallmatrix}\right)=\left(\begin{smallmatrix} r & 0\\0 & r \end{smallmatrix}\right)\left(\begin{smallmatrix} \cos \phi & -\sin \phi \\ \sin \phi & \cos \phi \end{smallmatrix}\right)$. In German this is called [Drehstreckung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drehstreckung#Zentrum_im_Ursprung). I tried to find translations to English and found [rotation-dilation](https://www.linguee.com/german-english/translation/drehstreckung.html), [spiral similarity, similarity transformation](https://www.dict.cc/deutsch-englisch/Drehstreckung.html).

Comment: Or if you use Google Translate, "twist extension".

Comment: +1. I commented about "roto-scaling" under the question, but I think "roto-dilation" is better.

Comment: Tristan Needham's "Visual Complex Analysis" refers to such transformations as "amplitwists."  (As far as I know, he invented this term.)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is any "standard" or "canonical" term for such matrices in cited references.

Writing something like

> Let $P$ be a matrix of the form $\left(\begin{array}{cc}
> a & -b \\
> b & a
> \end{array}\right)$, where $a,b$ are real numbers, ...

in an article is clear enough. Whether one needs a specific "name" for such matrices depends on *what* one wants to do with them, as long as it does not obstruct the clear delivery of mathematical communication. For instance, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Matrix_representation_of_complex_numbers) Wikipedia article called it "matrix representation of complex numbers". One may want to call it like that if one wants to emphasize its relation to complex numbers. Bob's daughter in high school may want to call it a "kitty" matrix in her report of exploring special matrices.

If it were for commenting on a piece of Python code as you mentioned at the beginning, I may simply delete it if it only describes a subset of the matrices.